# ASP.NET C# Not checking user exists in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, exists

I create an if else statement to check whether a database exists in DB, but ASP does not check it?

I think I am doing this wrong.

This is my code...

```
 SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM [Users] WHERE Username='" + @username + "'", Connect);

        int exist = check.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (exist > 0)
        {
            txtuser.Text = "User already exists";
        } else 
        // Insert the non-existing data to database
```

Comment: Please parameterize your query, consider the username `' drop table [Users] --` http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: I don't understand parameterize, but I'll read the link you give me. Thanks

Comment: `SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM [Users] WHERE Username='" + @username + "'", Connect);` would become `SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM [Users] WHERE Username='@username'", Connect);
check.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", @username));` Just trying to save you headaches down the road ;)

Comment: @mlorbetske Ah, thanks. Meaning to say, the other code is easier to read/ neater. I'll try to use that later. \o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like tthis...

```
int exist =(int) check.ExecuteScalar()
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()`  returns the number of rows affected in database.But here you are not updating or inserting so it will return 0 always.

Comment: welcome @Belzelga..... but dont forget to accept the answer,,unless you find better answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but it says 'You can accept an answer in 2 minutes' :D